# how to select radio button based on assignment of a textual value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vuejs3` with `options api`

as shown in the code posted below, the vue components has a radio button as an input. the `RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo` is the child component. i make the binding in the parent component as shown below in section `paretn component`.
what i am trying to do is, if the `vModelTimeSeriesAgo` is assigned to, for example, the textual value `first`, it should be checked, and not checked for any other textual values

how can i achieve that please

**RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo.vue**:

```
<template>
    <cds-radio>
        <label>{{ tempTextTimeSeriesAgo }}</label>
        <input
            type="radio"
            :value="vModelTimeSeriesAgo"
            @input="$emit('update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo', $event.target.value)"
            @change="onTimeSeriesAgoChanged()"/>
    </cds-radio>
</template>

<script>
import { NDVIGuiConstants } from './resources/NDVIComparisonGuiConstants.js';
export default {
    name: 'RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo',
    date() {
        return {};
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        tempTextTimeSeriesAgo: {
            type: String,
            default: NDVIGuiConstants.CONST_RADIO_BUTTON_TIME_SERIES_AGO.description,
        },
    },
    emits: ['update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo'],
    computed: {
        vModelTimeSeriesAgo: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.vModelTimeSeriesAgo:', this.vModelTimeSeriesAgo);
                return this.vModelTimeSeriesAgo;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.vModelTimeSeriesAgo:', value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelTimeSeriesAgo', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onTimeSeriesAgoChanged() {
            console.log('onTimeSeriesAgoChanged');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

**parent component**

```
<template>
    <RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo v-model:vModelTimeSeriesAgo="vModelTimeSeriesAgo"></RadioBtnTimeSeriesAgo>
</template>
```